# Install YII framework in xampp for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yii, installation, xampp

I m not any knowledge of YII framework just start work on YII . I want to install YII framework in my system .
So please let me how i install .

Comment: Begin Here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

Comment: those are the 4 videos that got me started with yii
http://www.yiiframework.com/screencasts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the yii zip file and unzip it.
Then copy the unzipped folder to:

```
/var/www/htdocs/
(Default Location)
```

Then run the following command :

```
/var/www/htdocs/Yii/framework/yiic webapp anyname
```

Done!!!
Open your browser and type "localhost/anyname"

Answer (score 1):

Download the YII framework from the website

Extract the folder in Downloads

Open the Terminal

**sudo su**
(enter the password)

**cd Downloads**
ls (the yii file will appear in that list)

**mv yii /var/www** (move that folder to www folder)

**cd /var/www** (check tht file is there by ls )

create a sample project

**mkdir folder_name**

**cd /var/www**

**php  yii/framework/yiic.php webapp /var/www/folder_name**

**create web application under '/var/www/folder_name' [yes][no]**

type yes

Folder permission in terminal

sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/one(folder name)

Answer (score 0):

Download the YII framework from the website

Extract into htdocs

Come out of htdocs folder

Create a sampleproject folder and give 777 permission

In here i created test as a sample project

Type the following in termial

**php yii/framework/yiic,php webapp  /var/www/yii/test**

[this is my location]
It will ask to create project or not ,give yes

and in browser type  localhost/yii/test

For More Details refer this below link

http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-install-yii-framework-on-ubuntu.html