# how to install Yii framework

Tags: yii, cmd

I'm new to Yii Framework.

I have downloaded the framework and moved to the webroot(in linux), and execute the command "yiic webapp ../../testapplication".

But i got the error as "command not found"[image].

[Install YII framework in xampp for ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422523/install-yii-framework-in-xampp-for-ubuntu)

I have followed these steps. But I couldn't succeed.

Please help me on this.

Comment: here is an easy to follow tutorial on setting up the yii framework - http://yiitutorials.net/easy/step-by-step-guide-setup-the-yii-framework

Comment: Thai Tran, thanks for your help. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```
./yiic
```

to explicitly name the executable (because `yiic` alone is not in you `$PATH`).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is:

```
$ /path/to/yiic webapp /path/to/webapp
```

I suggest you to do this:

```
$ cd /var/www
$ mkdir yourapp
$ cd yourapp
$ git clone git@github.com:yiisoft/yii
$ ./yii/framework/yiic webapp .
```

When a new version of yii is released ...

```
$ cd /var/www/yourapp/yii
$ git pull origin master
```

Very easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

At First Go to the xampp php.exe folder in cmd and after that run this command

**php yii/framework/yiic.php webapp myfirstsite**

It's only for windows xampp or wamp any server